# Terminology of different equilibria?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, definition, equilibrium

I've heard many [equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_equilibrium) terms:

1. Translational equilibrium
2. Rotational equilibrium
3. Static equilibrium
4. Dynamic equilibrium

The different terminology is slightly confusing. My understanding is as follows:

Translational equilibrium refers the equilibrium position when the resultant force is 0. Rotational equilibrium is when the net moment on an object is 0. An object could be in translational equilibrium without being in rotational equilibrium if the forces act on different lines of action.

Translational equilibrium encompasses the terms static and dynamic equilibrium. Static equilibrium is when the net force is 0. However the object remains at rest. Dynamic equilibrium is when the net force is 0. However the object remains in motion.

Is this correct?